# How to change direction of dialog texts to RTL in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have the following codes in my login page:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: . . .
        .
        .
        .
         showDialog(
             context: context,
             barrierDismissible: false,
             builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
             title: const Text('خطا'),
             content: Text('جهت تست'),
             actions: [
                TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                       Navigator.pop(context);
                       },
                       child: const Text("تایید"))
                   ],
                ),
            );
}
```

When I run the code, everything is in RTL mode but the dialog is in LTR mode. How can I make it RTL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap the widget returned in the showDialog with a `Directionality`:

```
showDialog(
             context: context,
             barrierDismissible: false,
             builder: (context) => Directionality(textDirection: /* your text direction*/, child: AlertDialog(
             title: const Text('خطا'),
             content: Text('جهت تست'),
             actions: [
                TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                       Navigator.pop(context);
                       },
                       child: const Text("تایید"))
                   ],
                ),
            ),);
```

With changing `/* your text direction*/` with your desired direction.

Answer (score 3):

The best and shortest way to set RTL configuration for the entire app.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Directionality( // add this
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, // set this property 
        child: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

If you need to display text in reverse direction then just set it's textdirection property to TextDirection.rtl.

**OR :**

Example code for TextField widget,

```
TextField(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Enter Pashto Name",
  ),
),
```

Example code for Text widget,

```
Text(
  "This text is in the other direction!"
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace  **[textDirection: TextDirection.rtl] to [textAlign: TextAlign.right]** because TextDirection.rtl cause special character-related problem https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/133317

```
TextField(
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Enter Name",
          ),
        )
```